# HTML5 "required" validation is not showing error message in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

This is a peculiar problem but is happening only in a particular version of Mozilla Firefox 53.0b9. The HTML5 "required" validation is not showing any error message but for Firefox 52.0.2 and 54.0a2 it is working fine.

Please suggest me a solution to this problem or provide me with any article where I can find that this is a Firefox 53.0b9 bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use javascript validation?

Comment: javascript validation is used but the 'required' attribute is used for the tooltip type error message. Could you suggest any kind of solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep it is a bug in Firefox 53, here is the bug report for it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1358487

Comment: Thanks Dave.. this link is just what I need